# Understanding the offset fields in the OVERLAPPED structure

Tags: c++, winapi

I am going through some code that uses `ReadFile` and specifies an `OVERLAPPED` type.

From what I understand so far from reading other posts, this is what I got.

If you wanted to start a `ReadFile` at the 8th byte of the file, you would set the `Offset` variable of `OVERLAPPED` to 8 and the `OffsetHigh` variable to 0 before passing the `OVERLAPPED` to `ReadFile`. This makes sense.

Now, what happens if we set `OffsetHigh` to 1?

Comment: Have you read the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped)?

Comment: Presumably it would try to read from byte 4294967296 in the file.

Comment: You'll start reading at offset 4GB+8.  OVERLAPPED is very, very old and dates from an era when C compilers did not yet support a 64-bit integral type.

Comment: not think that `OVERLAPPED` declared before `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` and `ReadFile` before `ZwReadFile` and `LARGE_INTEGER`. this is bad design but not compiler not support

Comment: @RbMm I'm not going to claim to know what ReadFile looked like in 16-bit Windows but the reason might come from somewhere between Windows 3 and 95? I also think I read somewhere that the QuadPart in LARGE_INTEGER used to be a double because there was no __int64.

Comment: @Anders - i also dont know when and where `OVERLAPPED`  first declared ( i never view even Windows 98, not to mention earlier versions). but i guess that `OVERLAPPED` declared after `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` (and windows nt) not before. and when i say about *bad design* i mean basically that in `OVERLAPPED` merged several parameters - `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`, `ByteOffset`, `hEvent` and even `ApcContext == 0` condition (by setting its low-order bit in .. *hEvent* ! ). in case asynchronous io - we must keep alive all `OVERLAPPED` until I/O not completed, while really need only iosb..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual offset is a 64-bit integer. The `Offset` field is the low 32 bits, and the `OffsetHigh` field is the high 32 bits.  This is stated as much in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped):

> `Offset`
>
> **The low-order portion of the file position** at which to start the I/O request, as specified by the user.
>
> ...
>
> `OffsetHigh`
>
> **The high-order portion of the file position** at which to start the I/O request, as specified by the user.
>
> ...
>
> The `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members **together represent a 64-bit file position**. It is a byte offset from the start of the file or file-like device, and it is specified by the user; the system will not modify these values. The calling process must set this member before passing the `OVERLAPPED` structure to functions that use an offset, such as the `ReadFile` or `WriteFile` (and related) functions.

This split in low/high bits is a remnant from the early days of C when 64-bit integer types were not commonly available yet (this is why structs like `(U)LARGE_INTEGER` even exist in the Win32 API).

So:

| Offset | OffsetHigh | 64bit Value (Hex) | 64bit Value (Decimal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0 | 0x00000000'00000008 | 8 |
| 8 | 1 | 0x00000001'00000008 | 4'294'967'304 |